# Crystal Reports Cascading Static Parameters

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, cascading

I have a report with 3 parameters (ReportType, DateRange, OrderNum) and I'd like to cascade them if possible. My record filter is working properly.

ReportType = 1 = All, 2 = By Date Range, 3 = By Order#

```
If Report Type = 1, then don't prompt for anything else
If Report Type = 2, Prompt for DateRange Parameter
If Report Type = 3, Prompt for OrderNum Parameter
```

DateRange ties directly to a field, but OrderNum does not because the DB field has leading 0's and I don't expect the user to enter the correct number of 0's

Comment: Please state exactly what your question is.  What is an example of the output you wanted to see?  What are you actually seeing instead?

Comment: didn't get your question